# Are "having" and "where" totally equivalent when there is no "group by" clause?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance, syntax

Generally, is there any difference between `having` and `where` clauses when there is no `group by` clause (particularly in MySQL, PostrgrSQL, Oracle and MSSQL)?

`select * from user where foo > 3`
seems to be equivalent to
`select * from user having foo > 3`

Comment: care to share some examples and trials?

Comment: I guess this is supported only in `Mysql`

Comment: @Prdp The SQL standard requires that `HAVING` must reference only columns in the `GROUP BY` clause or columns used in aggregate functions. It also specifies that if the query uses [`GROUP BY` aggregate functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html) but it doesn't contain a `GROUP BY` clause, an implicit group is created using all the records filtered by the `WHERE` clause. (e.g. `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1`)

Answer (score 3):

There's at least one **huge** difference:

The `HAVING` clause will **not use an index**:

```
explain select username from users having user_id = 32654456;
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table  | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | users | index | NULL          | PRIMARY | 32      | NULL | 661107 | Using index |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
```

While the `WHERE` clause will:

```
explain select username from users where user_id = 32654456;
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table  | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | users | const | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 32      | const |    1 | Using index |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
```

Comment: This conflicts with the second part of axiac answer.

Comment: What version of MySQL do you use? The [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/where-optimizations.html) of all 5.* versions says *"`HAVING` is merged with `WHERE` if you do not use `GROUP BY` or aggregate functions (`COUNT()`, `MIN()`, and so on)."*. It should apply to your query too.

Comment: I mean if they are merged why having is not able to use indexes in your example?

Comment: I have version 5.5.43

Comment: Please note that neither my query nor OPs are having any WHERE clauses, so there's nothing to be *merged*. I couldn't find in the docs something to say that the HAVING clause is *transformed* in a WHERE clause if possible.

Comment: Hmm... you are right. I ran a test and I got even worse execution plan (`type = 'ref'` vs. `type = 'all'` for `SELECT *`). It seems the documentation is broken. :-(

Comment: I don't think it's broken - I think we need to interpret it **literary** as my above comment :)

Comment: @TudorConstantin I think if there is no where clause the situation is clearer and the having clause can be considered where without merging.

Comment: Yes, it could, but it seems that as of today, it's not. On the other hand, if I were a MySQL developer, I'd ask myself - *why should I even implement such an optimization? besides some "what if..." questions, is there somebody to use such a feature? why wouldn't they use the WHERE clause up front*

Comment: @Tudor Do you mean if you have a query with clause x and y in where and another statement with clause x in where any clause y in having they will run identically? but there performance of x and y in having is worse? It does not make sense.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work. I compared two queries similar to yours, both having a `WHERE` clause (one of them contains two conditions, the other splits the conditions between `WHERE` and `HAVING`). They still produce different execution plans and the one with `HAVING` performs worse.

Comment: Anyway, if the conditions in `HAVING` clause are not moved into the `WHERE` clause, the `HAVING` is processed at the end, just before sending the result set back to the client. The `WHERE` clause is processed very early in the query executions. This makes a huge difference when the query joins tables.

Answer (score 3):

This is what the documentation says on the [`SELECT` statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) page:

> - The `HAVING` clause is applied nearly last, just before items are sent to the client, with no optimization. (`LIMIT` is applied after `HAVING`.)
>
>   The SQL standard requires that `HAVING` must reference only columns in the `GROUP BY` clause or columns used in aggregate functions. However, MySQL supports an extension to this behavior, and permits `HAVING` to refer to columns in the `SELECT` list and columns in outer subqueries as well.
> - Do not use `HAVING` for items that should be in the `WHERE` clause. For example, do not write the following:
>
>   ```
>   SELECT col_name FROM tbl_name HAVING col_name > 0
>   ```
>
>   Write this instead:
>
>   ```
>   SELECT col_name FROM tbl_name WHERE col_name > 0
>   ```
> - The `HAVING` clause can refer to aggregate functions, which the `WHERE` clause cannot:
>
>   ```
>   SELECT user, MAX(salary) FROM users GROUP BY user HAVING MAX(salary) > 10
>   ```

Also, on the [optimization of `WHERE` clauses](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/where-optimizations.html) page:

> Some of the optimizations performed by MySQL follow:
>
> - `HAVING` is merged with `WHERE` if you do not use `GROUP BY` or aggregate functions (`COUNT()`, `MIN()`, and so on).<sup>1</sup>
> - Before each row is output, those that do not match the `HAVING` clause are skipped.

<sup>1</sup> Some tests revealed that the merging of `HAVING` into `WHERE` (when the above conditions apply) does not make these clauses equivalent. Using the [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-output.html) statement revealed that the indexes on columns from the `HAVING` clause are not used.

Also read @tudor-constantin's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36963451/4265352) and the discussion it generated.

**How it works**

The `HAVING` clause is processed at the end, just before the result set is sent back to the client while the `WHERE` clause is processed early in the query execution.

It makes a big difference when the query `JOIN`s two or more tables. A non-matching `WHERE` condition that uses columns from the second table stops the retrieval of data from the second and the next tables but when it stays in the `HAVING` clause it lets the data retrieval continue and drops the row after a lot of hard work was done to get it.

A difference also exists for queries that use a single table: the indexes on columns from the `HAVING` clauses are not used to filter the rows read from the table. Indexes are used to filter what rows are read from the table (sometimes an index can even suppress the read of the table data entirely) and for sorting. Not using indexes leads to slow queries.

---

#### The final resolution

The `WHERE` and `HAVING` clauses are not equivalent. Even if they produce the same final result, there is a huge difference in the way the queries are executed.

Putting in the `HAVING` clause conditions that can stay in the `WHERE` clause (see above) produces a waste of resources (CPU processing power, data-storage access, time) for nothing.

Comment: If they are merged why we should not use having instead of where? Also if they are merged why do they are different in running according to the other answer?

Answer (score 2):

Another diff...  Aliases are recognized by `HAVING` but not `WHERE`:

```
mysql> SELECT city AS c FROM Canada WHERE c='Toronto';
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'c' in 'where clause'
mysql> SELECT city AS c FROM Canada HAVING c='Toronto';
+---------+
| c       |
+---------+
| Toronto |
+---------+
```

(Further checks showed that `HAVING` is not using an index when `WHERE` is.  Version 5.6.12.)